# how can I add (subtract, etc.) two numbers with bash?

Tags: bash, scripting, variable

I can read the numbers and operation in with:

```
echo "First number please"
read num1
echo "Second number please"
read num2
echo "Operation?"
read op
```

but then all my attempts to add the numbers fail:

```
case "$op" in
  "+")
    echo num1+num2;;
  "-")
    echo `num1-num2`;;
esac
```

Run:

```
First number please
1
Second mumber please
2
Operation?
+
```

Output:

```
num1+num2
```

...or...

```
echo $num1+$num2;;

# results in: 1+2
```

...or...

```
echo `$num1`+`$num2`;;

# results in: ...line 9: 1: command not found
```

Seems like I'm getting strings still perhaps when I try add add ("2+2" instead of "4").

Comment: I edited your title because this is a good general question, and if you narrowed the context down you would have realized this has nothing to do with `case` or anything except one line: `echo $num+$num`, since that *will reproduce the problem exactly*.  The idea with minimizing context in programming questions is explained here: http://sscce.org/

Comment: +1 Hi goldilocks, yes that became clear to me afterwards, but yes I totally agree with your line of reasoning and yes, the more specific and 'singular' a question is the better.  I welcome your edit(s) :)  Thank You :)

Answer (score 283, accepted):

[Arithmetic in POSIX shells](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_04) is done with `$` and double parentheses `(( ))`:

```
echo "$(($num1+$num2))"
```

You can assign from that; also note the `$` operators on the variable names inside `(())` are optional):

```
num1="$((num1+num2))"
```

There is also `expr`:

```
expr $num1 + $num2
```

In scripting `$(())` is preferable since it avoids a fork/execute for the `expr` command.

Comment: Or even directly `echo $(($num1$op$num2))` without involving `case`.

Comment: There's no `case` involved here.

Comment: No, but you used literal `+`, so will need the `case` outside to handle the subtraction separately.

Comment: @manatwork : You mean eliminate the `case` from the OP's code with `echo $(($num1$op$num2))` -- that will work, but using the `case` is more robust since you can handle errors with a default `*`.

Comment: +1 to both of you.  I was using case (might not have shown it at the start) but as you both realized the problem wasn't about the case.

Comment: The `$((..))` arithmetic evaluation is executed by `bash`, whereas `expr` is executed as a separate process. Hence, the latter is slower than `$((..))`. Use `expr` only on systems where arithmetic evaluation is not supported (`sh!=bash`).

Comment: @SergeStroobandt: IIRC, `(())` arithmetic contexts are part of POSIX sh.  You can do `((newvar = num1 + num2))` as its own command, or C-style for loops.  Some non-POSIX shells don't support it, though.  Also, `echo $(expr)` makes no sense.  Why capture expr output just to put it on echo's commandline?  Just so it can be word-split / glob-expanded?

Comment: Only expressions `$((...))` are defined by POSIX; stand-alone statements `((...))` are a `bash` extension.

Comment: `$[...]` is an old, pre-POSIX notation for arithmetic expressions. Recognize it, but don't use it in new code. (It's not even mentioned in the man page anymore.)

Comment: @chepner Thx.  Edited.

Comment: Note that you can write `var` instead of `$var` (the `$` prefix is not needed) inside the expression: `echo $(( num1 + num2 ))`

Comment: I agree with @Philipp and want to add that `num1 + num2` without the `$` sign reinforces the fact you are in a math statement. Plus `shellcheck` will probably nag you to death if you use `$` inside the command.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work with decimal numbers

Answer (score 19):

The existing answer is pure bash, so it will be faster than this, but it can only handle integers. If you need to handle floats, you have to use the external program `bc`.

```
$ echo 'scale=4;3.1415+9.99' | bc
13.1315
```

The `scale=4` tells `bc` to use four decimal places. See `man bc` for more information.

Comment: Note that while `bash` doesn't support floating point arithmetics with `$((...))`, many shells (`ksh93`, `zsh`, `yash` at least) do. The advantage of `bc` is that it supports arbitrary precision while shell arithmetics is limited to the processor's `double` type. Note that you don't need to set `scale` here. For additions, the `scale` parameter is not used. The scale of `3.1415+9.99` will be derived from that of the operands (here 4).

Comment: How to do the math if one value is `450` and the other is decimal stored on a variable `$mynumber`? For example, `450-$mynumber`.

Comment: @sigur `echo "450-$mynumber" | bc` should do it. If you want a variable to expand you have to use double quotes rather than single quotes.

Comment: @evilsoup, now it works like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: `computedval=$(echo 'scale=10;var1-var2' | bc)` doesn't work, nor does `computedval=$(echo 'scale=10;$var1-$var2' | bc)`

Comment: Found one that worked: `computedval=$(bc <<< "scale=10; $val1-$val2")`

Answer (score 10):

You can also use `$[ ... ]` structure. In this case, we use built-in mechanizm in Bash, which is faster and a bit more convenient to use. Since we know that everything between $[, and ] is treated as an expression, we don't need to precede the variables with `$`. Similarily, we do not need to secure `*` from treating it like a pattern.

```
num1=2
num2=3
echo $[num1 + num2]
5
```

Comment: Is it safe to assume this isn't POSIX compliant, but Bash specific?

Comment: The `$[ expr ]` syntax is deprecated and should not be used anymore. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2415724/313501

Answer (score 5):

```
echo `expr $a + $b`   
echo `expr $a - $b`   
echo `expr $a \* $b`   
echo `expr $a / $b`
```

Note the `\` before the `*` (for multiplication),
the whole expression has to be within the backquotes `.

Comment: `expr` is not necessary, and it's never necessary to capture the standard output of a command just to write it back to standard output.

Answer (score 2):

minimalist

```
total=0
((total+=qty))
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the sequence of inputs you request from the user, it seems you are using *reverse polish notation.*

> ```
> echo "First number please"
> read num1
> echo "Second number please"
> read num2
> echo "Operation?"
> read op
> ```

You may do better just to use `dc` (desk calculator) directly, since that is what it is for.

```
DESCRIPTION
       Dc is a reverse-polish desk calculator which supports unlimited pre-
       cision arithmetic.
```

Example session using `dc`:

```
$ dc
1 2 + p    # This part is typed; the result comes next.
3
q  # This is also typed.
$
```

Or, non-interactively:

```
$ dc -e '1 2 + p'
3
$
```