# How does bash's arithmetic work?

Tags: bash, shell, arithmetic

```
 read num1
 2
 read num2
 5
 echo "$((num1+num2))"
 7
 echo "$(($num1+$num2))"
 7
```

I referred [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93029/how-can-i-add-subtract-etc-two-numbers-with-bash).

I don't understand how the above both expressions yields same result? Please explain.

```
    echo "$[num1+num2]"
```

It doesn't work as suggested in that question. Am i doing anything wrong?

```
    echo 'expr "$num1" + "$num2"`
```

also not working. Please provide some suggestions.

Comment: If downvoter comments the reason, it ll be helpful for the beginners like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In POSIX shell, [Arithmetic Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04) has form:

```
$((expression))
```

If expression contains variables, and those variables contain valid integer value - leading plus or minus is fine - then `"$((var))"` and `"$(($var))"` will return the same result (Note: [using unsanitized data in Shell Arithmetic evaluation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/172103/security-implications-of-using-unsanitized-data-in-shell-arithmetic-evaluation/172109#172109) leads to security implication).

The form [$[expression]](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/arith) is not defined by POSIX, is deprecated and will be remove in next version of `bash`.

The [expr](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/expr.html) utility can be used to do arithmetic. In your case, you used wrong syntax for [command substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03), it's a backstick, not a single quote:

```
echo `expr "$num1" + "$num2"`
```

But you should use `"$()"` form instead.

Answer (score 3):

To evaluate an arithmetic expression, the shell first expands variable and command substitutions inside it. For example, in `echo "$(($num1+$num2))"`, the first thing that happens is that `$num1` and `$num2` are replaced by the variables' values. The expression becomes `2+5`. This is parsed as an arithmetic expression and evaluated to the number 7. The result of parsing and expanding `"$(($num1+$num2))"` is thus `7`.

Arithmetic expressions can contain variable names. These are evaluated to the value of the variable. Thus `$((num1+num2))` is the arithmetic expression `num1+num2` (whereas `$(($num1+$num2))` is the arithmetic expression `2+5`). In this case the result is the same.

The two expressions are different when the value of `num1` or `num2` isn't just a sequence of digits. For example, consider the following snippet:

```
a="1+2"
echo "$(($a * 4))"
echo "$((a * 4))"
```

In the second line, the arithmetic expression to be evaluated is `1+2 * 4`. This is parsed as 1 + (2 × 4) since multiplication has a higher precedence than addition. The fact that the plus sign came from the expansion of a variable is forgotten by the time the arithmetic evaluation takes place. The result is the number 9, so the first call to `echo` prints `9`.

The behavior of the third line depends on the shell. Some shells (e.g. dash) complain that `a` does not contain a valid numeric value. Other shells (e.g. ksh, bash, zsh) treat the value of `a` as a subexpression which is evaluated to get the value to use in the main expression. That is, in these other shells, the value of `a` is evaluated to `3`, and the arithmetic expression calculates 3 × 4 so the result is 12.

Finally, `$[…]` is a deprecated, non-standard variant of `$((…))`. The `expr` utility is an older way of making arithmetic calculations in shell scripts, dating back from the time when shells didn't have a built-in arithmetic syntax. `expr "$num1" + "$num2"` prints 7, as does the redundant `` echo `expr "$num1" + "$num2"` `` (you mistyped one of the quotes).

Comment: Great Explanations. Good Teacher You Are :)